# Setting up a vector in C++

Tags: c++, class, vector

I am trying to set up a vector to store a group of baseball pitchers.  I want to store one pitcher's name Joe Smith (string) and his earned run average for the last two years - 2.44 and 3.68.  I also want to store a second pitcher's name - Bob Jones (string) and his earned run average 5.22 and 4.78.  This is part of a larger homework assignment but I only just started using vectors.  The problem I'm having is my textbook says that vectors can only be used to store values of the same type and all the examples I'm finding primarily use integer values.  For example I found this example on cplusplus.com

```
// constructing vectors
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
unsigned int i;

// constructors used in the same order as described above:
std::vector<int> first;                                // empty vector of ints
std::vector<int> second (4,100);                       // four ints with value 100
std::vector<int> third (second.begin(),second.end());  // iterating through second
std::vector<int> fourth (third);                       // a copy of third

// the iterator constructor can also be used to construct from arrays:
int myints[] = {16,2,77,29};
std::vector<int> fifth (myints, myints + sizeof(myints) / sizeof(int) );

std::cout << "The contents of fifth are:";
for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = fifth.begin(); it != fifth.end(); ++it)
std::cout << ' ' << *it;
std::cout << '\n';

return 0;
}
```

Is there any way I could alter this code to accept a string and two doubles?  I don't need to get any input from the user I just need to initialize the two pitchers in int main().  I already set up a class for them, shown below, but the assignment requires a vector.

```
#ifndef PITCHER_H
#define PITCHER_H
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Pitcher
{
private:
    string _name;
    double _ERA1;
    double _ERA2;

public:
    Pitcher();
    Pitcher(string, double, double);
    ~Pitcher();
    void SetName(string);
    void SetERA1(double);
    void SetERA2(double);
    string GetName();
    double GetERA1();
    double GetERA2();       

};

#endif

#include "Pitcher.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

Pitcher::Pitcher()
{
}

Pitcher::Pitcher(string name, double ERA1, double ERA2)
{
_name = name;
_ERA1 = ERA1;
_ERA2 = ERA2;
}

Pitcher::~Pitcher()
{
}

void Pitcher::SetName(string name)
{
_name = name;
}

void Pitcher::SetERA1(double ERA1)
{
_ERA1 = ERA1;
}

void Pitcher::SetERA2(double ERA2)
{
_ERA2 = ERA2;
}

string Pitcher::GetName()
{
return _name;
}

double Pitcher::GetERA1()
{ 
return _ERA1;
}

double Pitcher::GetERA2()
{
return _ERA2;
}

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Pitcher.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

Pitcher Pitcher1("Joe Smith", 2.44, 3.68);

cout << Pitcher1.GetName() << endl;
cout << Pitcher1.GetERA1() << endl;
cout << Pitcher1.GetERA2() << endl;

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I think you want to store a vector of pitchers

```
 vector<Pitcher> pitchers;
 Pitcher p1("name", 0.5, 0.1); //create a pitcher
 pitchers.push_back(p1); //add the pitcher to the vector
 ...//fill in some other pitchers
 //to print all the pitchers
 for(unsigned i = 0; i < pitchers.size(); ++i)
 {
      cout << pitchers[i].GetName() << " " << pitchers[i].GetERA1() << "\n";
 }
```

Hope the example clears some things up.

Comment: this approach is better then mine, you don't use pointers, just to remember that if you want to keep this alive after the scope ends you need a pointer.

Comment: @demonofnight The Pitcher objects will be copied into the vector, and so their scope will be the same as that of the vector. eg, if the vector is returned, it will contain valid Pitcher objects.

Comment: @Porkbutts More to the point: given the definition of `Pitcher`, you should probably never have a pointer to it.  You can access it in the vector using `[]` (or iterators, or `back()` or `front()`).  If you want to keep it locally, you take a copy.

Comment: I didn't use the pointer, you were correct I just needed a vector of pitchers, this was a huge help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like

```
vector<Pitcher*> *vecPit=new vector<Pitcher*>();
```

you add with

```
vecPit->push_back(new Pitcher("string", 2.123, 2.123)
```

Comment: if you want this type of thing - use a smart, not a raw, pointer. eg. `vector<shared_ptr<Pitcher> > vecPit;` add with `vecPit.push_back(make_shared<Pitcher>("string", 1,2));` as then you won't have to worry about deleting the contained objects.

Comment: How would you access the new pitcher after you push_back?  Just curious, as I am learning C++ myself in school.  I've finished the book we're reading in class after reading for about 3 days straight trying to soak in everything.  I just remember vectors as being good because they don't have a fixed size.  @demonofnight

Comment: @gbjbaanb More concretely: you don't want this sort of thing.  Smart pointers are a work-around, but any sort of pointer is a design error.  Well written C++ uses value semantics whenever possible.

Comment: @CharlesAddis vecPit->at(pos)->SetName("asdasd"); You have the vecPit->size() or you can use iterator

Comment: Agree with James. You get the added benefit of spatial locality since vectors are backed by arrays. Use the pitcher objects rather than pointers to pitchers. Pointer to vector is fine, though I would prefer keeping a reference to the actual vector via member variable.